"Raison d'être" for Separable Spaces
A naive question about separable spaces:
Are there deeper reasons from viewpoint of functional analysis making these interesting? So far I know only only set theoretical advantages (=better "size control" wrt mapping spaces out of sep spaces) and intuitionistic reasons (as proofs involving these often can "avoid" axiom of choice).
For instance the latter point, the issue that some proof of results including separable spaces are "easier by avoiding axiom of choice" suggests that it's really about "simplifying" sometimes the proofs. But is there a significance on level of results themselves and not just giving alternative proofs? Ie are there some interesting results in FA which without separability would be plainly wrong?
In other words essentially the question is if separable spaces have also pure functional analytical & topological (in sense of point-set topology) significance?
They "appear" nice as the cardinality seems better contrallable, but it seems (at least to me) that this effect is purely psychological ("smaller spaces are easier to imagine"), or is there any even structural & formal significance making separable spaces "interesting"?

On that same page: embedding separable metric spaces

I don’t know if this counts, but plenty of definitions/results only work for separable structures. In my field of von Neumann algebras, for example, there is a unique hyperfinite type II$_1$ factor $R$, and this factor satisfies many nice properties. The corresponding statements for uncountable cardinalities are simply wrong. The direct integral theory of von Neumann algebras (as well as representations of $C^\ast$-algebras) only works assuming separability. It completely fails otherwise…

… The multiplication operator form of spectral theorem (at least in the way it is most useful and usually stated) only holds in separable Hilbert spaces, as otherwise you cannot get a single Borel positive measure that dominates the spectral measure. A separable $C^\ast$-algebra admits a faithful state, while nonseparable ones do not in general. (This corresponds to the classical measure theory fact that you can get faithful probability measures on Polish spaces, but you can’t in general if the spaces are not assumed separable.) In Banach space theory, Schauder basis…

… is only defined for separable Banach spaces. While the definition can be extended, it doesn’t work as well. (A correction: in my first comment I meant there is a unique separable hyperfinite type II$_1$ factor.)
